# Redux Saga - Why does yield all not wait for the put action to complete before proceeding

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to wait for all the put actions within my yieldall to complete before moving on to the next yield. I thought that that was what yieldall is supposed to achieve. I am new to Redux Saga hence there might be some details or logic that I am missing out on.

Here is my workerAnalytics (the first worker called using dispatch 'ANALYTICS')

```
export function* workerAnalytics(action) {
    console.log('here')
    let group = action.group
    yield put({ type: 'SHOW_LOADER', loading: action.loading })
    yield all([
        put({ type: 'BASIC_ANALYTICS', loading: 'client', group: group }),
        put({ type: 'BASIC_ANALYTICS', loading: 'KPI', group: group }),
        put({ type: 'BASIC_ANALYTICS', loading: 'country', group: group }),
        put({ type: 'BASIC_ANALYTICS', loading: 'estimated_revenue' }),
    ])
    console.log('there')
    yield put({ type: 'HIDE_LOADER', loading: action.loading })
}
```

my workerBasicAnalytics (called after watcherBasicAnalytics is called from dispatch type 'BASIC_ANALYTICS')

```
export function* workerBasicAnalytics(action) {
    try {
        let data;
        if (action.loading === 'KPI') { yield put({ type: 'SHOW_LOADER', loading: action.loading }) }
        data = action.loading === 'client' ? yield call(() => axiosInstance.get(`/customer-conversion/?group=${action.group}`)) :
            action.loading === 'KPI' ? yield call(() => axiosInstance.get(`/kpi/?group=${action.group}`)) :
                action.loading === 'country' ? yield call(() => axiosInstance.get(`/customer-country/?group=${action.group}`)) :
                    action.loading === 'estimated_revenue' ? yield call(() => axiosInstance.get('/estimated-revenue/')) : null
        yield put({ type: "STORE_DATA", payload: data.data, fetch: action.loading })
        if (action.loading === 'KPI') { yield put({ type: 'HIDE_LOADER', loading: action.loading }) }
        console.log(action.loading)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have console.log throughout my worker functions to keep track of which is executed first. The issue is that 'there' is logged right after 'here', when it should have been the individual workerBasicAnalytics console.log(action.loading) that should have been logged before the 'there' is logged, as the console.log('there') comes after the yieldall.

All help is appreciated, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if workerBasicAnalytics is even called? Or if you caught the error in catch handler?

**Update:**
You can do this:

```
yield all([
  workerBasicAnalytics({loading: 'client', group: group}), 
  workerBasicAnalytics({loading: 'KPI', group: group}
)]
```

Comment: yes workerBasicAnalytics is called as the console.log(action.loading) at the end of workerBasicAnalytics is logged, but the issue is that it is logged after the console.log('there') in the workerAnalytics function, which should not be the case as I wrapped the put(type: "BASIC_ANALYTICS") within a yieldall. Also, I wrapped it around a try and catch and there was no error caught

Comment: Okay, the problem is that **put** is a non-blocking dispatch effect, which doesn't wait for the response. You can either you **putResolve** (blocking) which waits for return of dispatched function or use **call** (blocking) directly instead of put.

Comment: oh i did not know put does not wait for the response. if i were to use call how do i use it along with my workerBasicAnalytics function?  sorry i am new to redux saga. also can i check if put does not wait for the response, then when i use yield put, what does the yield wait for?

Comment: updated above on how you can use. When you use yield put it wait for the function call to complete, not wait for the result.

Comment: it works! thank you so much :-) but can i check whats the difference between me calling workerBasicAnalytics vs me calling the call(workerBasicAnalytics)? and also since yield put waits for the function call to complete, am i right to assume that when i used put to dispatch the workerBasicAnalytics previously, it did not work as it just waits to the first yield in the workerBasicAnalytics and carries on already? hence i should only use yield put when i am dispatching an action that is a reducer (not a generator function)? but once again thank you so much for your answer :-)

Comment: Yes, you can use call(workerBasicAnalytics, ...args), they both are the same. In case of put, the functions are called and it moves on to next yield, it doesn't wait for return which is similar to asynchronous dispatch function.

Comment: oh okay thanks! in that case, i used yield put in my workerBasicAnalytics to dispatch the actions that would alter the store using reducers, would it affect anything since it doesnt wait for the response from that put? for example, i used yield put for the SHOW_LOADER and HIDE_LOADER action, which changes the state.loading accordingly.

Comment: That's okay, since you expect nothing in return but just to update the state.